# Displaying numbers in a particular manner

Tags: java

How can we write a program to display a number of series like the following:

```
56789
6789
789
89
9
```

I have written the following program, but it's not giving the desired output. Something is missing. What condition is required for the completion of the problem?

```
public class displaying {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       int x, y, z;

       for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
           for (y = 5; y < 10; y++) {
               z = x + y;
               System.out.println(z);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output is it giving you? How is it different from what you're expecting?

Comment: You're very close. Try `y = 5 + x` in the loop initialization.

Comment: you mean in the for loop where i am initialzing the variable of y or inside it??

Comment: nope..its not giving the exact output

Comment: And you might also want to use `print()` instead of `println()` on the inner loop, and have a blank `println()` below the inner loop

Comment: Do you have to actually use numbers (like `int`)?  If it were me, I'd initialize a `String` to `"56789"` and then use `substring()`.

Comment: yup i used the exact numbers...not a String

Comment: if anyone find this solution please share it..

Comment: You can try debugging the code by putting break points (In case you are using a IDE like eclipse). That would help you understand the flow of the code and where you are going wrong. This would improve your debugging skills and code flow knowledge :)

Comment: I will definately take your point @Sashwat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for (y = 5; y < 10 - x; y++) {
       z = x + y;
       System.out.print(z);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

- You are using println which will add a new line character after z i.e. print your z values on new line. So use print method which wont add new line character and use println once you come out of your inner loop so you just get newline character.
- Your inner loop will always traverse from 5 to 9+y i.e. may goto 10/11 etc which is not what you want. So add to your loop 10-x value so you just get say n,n-1,n-2 values which can be improved further like `for (y = x + 5; y < 10; y++) {` and you can avoid the addition within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    Int I = 56789;
    Int v = 5;

    System.out.println (I);

    for (Int p = 0; p < 5; p++){

        I -= v*Math.pow (10, 10-v);
        v++;
        System.out.println(I);

    }

}
```

I wrote this on my phone so sorry if it's not formated correctly. I also didn't test it so it might not work

Comment: I reformatted this on my laptop because I refuse to torture myself by trying to write code on a phone.  Didn't test it, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int x, y;

    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for (y = x + 5; y < 10; y++) {
            System.out.print(y);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Before, your inner loop was: `for (y = 5; y < 10; y++)`. Doing so would cause every new count to start at 5. If everything else was correct, it would produce something like:

```
56789
56789
56789
56789
56789
```

Now the only other thing wrong was the `System.out.println(z);`, instead of `System.out.print(y);` in the inner loop. This would cause all your outputs to be printed on the same line. What you wanted was to print the inner outputs on the same line, but print a `'\n'` after, which you can do using a blank `System.out.println()`

Comment: thanx alex...keep helping..:)

Comment: Got it...almas also want to say the same thing..Now i have rectified the problem which you r pointing to..this problem giving me a headache from  yesterday...hehe..now after seeing the problem..it is so embarassing...

Comment: There's a lot of query in my head...i m learner now..so if i ask silly questions please don't joke at me...:D

Comment: Don't worry about it. Everybody had these questions at some point. Look on the bright side, at least you figured it out instead of having your headache extended until next week like they had to do before the invention of Stackoverflow :D

Comment: hahaha...i guess we are very lucky generation...ask a question and bam got the pin point solution..:)

Comment: Thanx for u all guys...you all made the stackoverflow at the top...everybody's contribution is very remarkable.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the obvious answer can be the hardest to spot...

```
   for (int x = 5; x <= 9; x++) {
       for (int y = x; y <= 9; y++) {
           System.out.print(y);
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
```

I think this is the loop that most closely describes the output you want.

Comment: Thank ajb..keep helping..there are lots of query's coming in future..:)